# Assigning the different value to parameters in Generate block in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, synthesis, hdl, rtl

I want to instantiate a module having parameters using generate block. But I want to *assign different values to parameter for different instantiation* of the module.

For example:

> *This is my module that I want to instantiate and it has parameters* DATA_WIDTH & SIZE_WIDTH .

```
module gen_module (
     input clk,
     input rst );

     parameter [3:0] DATA_WIDTH = 1;
     parameter [3:0] SIZE_WIDTH = 2;

endmodule
```

> This is another module in which I am instantiating **gen_module** using **generate** statement. (**But here I am using only one parameter value of** *D_WIDTH* and *S_WIDTH* **for all instantiation** )

[*It is working but with single value for all*]

```
module top_module ();

    wire clk;
    wire rst;

    parameter N = 5;
    parameter [3:0] D_WIDTH = 7;
    parameter [3:0] S_WIDTH = 4;

    genvar j;

    generate
        for(j = 0; j <= N; j=j+1) begin : GEN_BLOCK
           gen_module #(.DATA_WIDTH(D_WIDTH), .SIZE_WIDTH(S_WIDTH)) i_gen_module (
             .clk (clk),
             .rst (rst)
          );

        end
    endgenerate 
endmodule
```

But I want to do something like this statement. (As I know parameter array is not applicable in Verilog)

```
gen_module #(.DATA_WIDTH(D_WIDTH[j]), .SIZE_WIDTH(S_WIDTH[j])) i_gen_module (
```

Here I want to give different values to **D_WIDTH[j]** & **S_WIDTH[j]** and want to use them to assign to parameters (**DATA_WIDTH & SIZE_WIDTH**) in generate block.

[Here **J** will change with *for* loop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily in SystemVerilog as you can declare a parameter that is an array and then select index of the parameter array inside the generate loop. Most simulation and synthesis tools already support this.

If you need to stay in Verilog, you can pack values into a parameter and then select a slice of parameter

```
module top_module ();

    wire clk;
    wire rst;

    parameter N = 5;
    // assuming width can fit in 4 bits
    parameter [(N*4)-1:0] D_WIDTH = {4'd1,4'd2,4'd3,4'd4,4'd5};
    parameter [(N*4)-1:0] S_WIDTH = {4'd6,4'd7,4'd8,4'd9,4'd8};

    genvar j;

    generate
        for(j = 0; j < N; j = j+1) begin : GEN_BLOCK
           gen_module #(.DATA_WIDTH (D_WIDTH[j*4+:4]), .SIZE_WIDTH (S_WIDTH[j*4+:4])) i_gen_module (
              .clk (clk),
              .rst (rst)
          );

        end
    endgenerate 
endmodule
```